# Make xsd.exe utility generate schema with strong types

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have this sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>BBB</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>BBB</name>
  </item>
</DocumentElement>
```

I want to generate XSD schema using xsd.exe utility and run this command:

```
xsd.exe myXmlFile.xml
```

This is what I got on output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="DocumentElement" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="DocumentElement" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="item">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Notice both fields are string but I expected them to be an integer and a string.
If I generate schema in VS then I get a better result:

```
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
```

How can I make xsd.exe work like in VS?

Comment: Your original xml has no schema so there are no defined types.  I VS is giving a correct schema that you are using classes to generate the xml or have an xml that has a schema.

Comment: @jdweng how can I make xsd do the same?

Comment: Look at options by just typing .\xsd.exe

Comment: @jdweng that didn't help me. I dont have idea what schema to give to the xsd.

Comment: No sure why VS is working.  Either VS assumes all number are int or VS is getting an existing schema from your project data.

Comment: @jdweng VS doesnt know anything about that brand new XML file. I just manually created it and VS did the job...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to generate xsd files with strong types.

**First,** please generate a xsd file by using the command:

```
xsd D:\Sample.xml /outputdir:D:\
```

**Second**, please generate a class from the xsd file:

```
xsd D:\Sample.xsd /classes /outputdir:D:\
```

**Third**, please create a class library(.net framework 3.5) and add the generated class to the project, rebuild it.

**Fourth**, please change string type to int type about id.

public partial class DocumentElementItem {

```
private int idField;        //Change string to int

private string nameField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public int  id {          //Change string to int
    get {
        return this.idField;
    }
    set {
        this.idField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string name {
    get {
        return this.nameField;
    }
    set {
        this.nameField = value;
    }
}
```

}

**Finally**, please use the following command to generate a xsd file with strong types.

```
xsd "D:\Test\bin\Debug\Test.dll" /type:DocumentElementItem /outputdir:D:\
```

You will get the following xsd file.

[image]

Besides, you can see all the processes in the following picture.

[image]